# Why I can't login in symfony through programming?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony-security

I tried to login symfony by programming, but when redirect to new route the user return to anon. user.

**security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: pass
                        roles: ROLE_ADMIN

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login: ~

        login_firewall:
            pattern:   ^/login$
            anonymous: ~

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**loginAction**

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST')
    {
        $firewall = 'main';

        $user = new User('User', 'pass', array('ROLE_ADMIN'));

        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), $firewall, $user->getRoles());

        $this->get("security.token_storage")->setToken($token);

        $session = $this->get('session');
        $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));

        $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
        $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin'));
    }

    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render(
        'security/login.html.twig',
        array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        )
    );
}
```

**Problem:** The User login but when redirect to route admin return again to login with user anon.

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using?  Since 2.5 or so the session nonsense is not longer required.

Comment: Symfony version is 2.8.3

Answer (score 0):

You should remove

> form_login: ~

under main firewall in security.yml

In this case you will show an exception:

> Full authentication is required to access this resource

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple utility class that works for 2.8/3.0.  It shows the needed lines at the bottom.  If this sort of code does not work for you then you do indeed have some kind of firewall issue though of course I would assume you have mentioned it if your were getting exceptions:

```
class ProjectUserLoginUser
{
    /** @var  EventDispatcherInterface */
    private $eventDispatcher;

    /** @var  TokenStorageInterface */
    private $securityTokenStorage;

    private $firewallName; // main

    public function __construct(
        $firewallName,
        EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher,
        TokenStorageInterface    $securityTokenStorage
    )
    {
        $this->firewallName          = $firewallName;
        $this->eventDispatcher       = $eventDispatcher;
        $this->securityTokenStorage  = $securityTokenStorage;
    }
    public function loginUser(Request $request, UserInterface $user)
    {
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $this->firewallName, $user->getRoles());

        $this->securityTokenStorage->setToken($token);

        $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);

        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN, $event);
    }
}
```

Comment: same problem symfony doesn't store user in all routes, after redirect return again to login with anon user

Comment: Then it's a firewall configuration thing.  Use the default Symfony security.yml file to get things working  then add your adjustments back in.  I myself find that the whole access control stuff is more trouble than it's worth.  I just secure routes individually.